# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Compile for MIPS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, mips

I am trying to figure out how to compile a simple hello world in Visual Studio, but for MIPS processor.  Followed the guideline posted on MS [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254280%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Only difference is I am trying this on Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is a native C++ program." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tried compiling with the /QMR4100 options:

```
c:\Users\ukhan\Documents\Auto_Security\Test_Code>cl  /QMR4100 /EHsc forloop.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

**cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/QMR4100'**
forloop.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:forloop.exe
forloop.obj
```

So, I checked help for options and it does seem the command line option is not valid:

```
c:\Users\ukhan\Documents\Auto_Security\Test_Code>cl /?
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

                         C/C++ COMPILER OPTIONS


                              -OPTIMIZATION-

/O1 minimize space                      /O2 maximize speed
/Ob<n> inline expansion (default n=0)   /Od disable optimizations (default)
/Og enable global optimization          /Oi[-] enable intrinsic functions
/Os favor code space                    /Ot favor code speed
/Ox maximum optimizations
/favor:<blend|AMD64|INTEL64> select processor to optimize for, one of:
    blend - a combination of optimizations for several different x64 processors
    AMD64 - 64-bit AMD processors
    INTEL64 - Intel(R)64 architecture processors

                             -CODE GENERATION-

/GF enable read-only string pooling     /Gm[-] enable minimal rebuild
/Gy[-] separate functions for linker    /GS[-] enable security checks
/GR[-] enable C++ RTTI                  /GX[-] enable C++ EH (same as /EHsc)
/EHs enable C++ EH (no SEH exceptions)  /EHa enable C++ EH (w/ SEH exceptions)
/EHc extern "C" defaults to nothrow
/fp:<except[-]|fast|precise|strict> choose floating-point model:
    except[-] - consider floating-point exceptions when generating code
    fast - "fast" floating-point model; results are less predictable
    precise - "precise" floating-point model; results are predictable
    strict - "strict" floating-point model (implies /fp:except)
/Qfast_transcendentals generate inline FP intrinsics even with /fp:except
/GL[-] enable link-time code generation /GA optimize for Windows Application
/Ge force stack checking for all funcs  /Gs[num] control stack checking calls
/Gh enable _penter function call        /GH enable _pexit function call
/GT generate fiber-safe TLS accesses    /RTC1 Enable fast checks (/RTCsu)
/RTCc Convert to smaller type checks    /RTCs Stack Frame runtime checking
/RTCu Uninitialized local usage checks
/clr[:option] compile for common language runtime, where option is:
    pure - produce IL-only output file (no native executable code)
    safe - produce IL-only verifiable output file
    oldSyntax - accept the Managed Extensions syntax from Visual C++ 2002/2003
    initialAppDomain - enable initial AppDomain behavior of Visual C++ 2002
    noAssembly - do not produce an assembly
/homeparams Force parameters passed in registers to be written to the stack
/GZ Enable stack checks (/RTCs)
/arch:AVX enable use of Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions instructions

                              -OUTPUT FILES-

/Fa[file] name assembly listing file    /FA[scu] configure assembly listing
/Fd[file] name .PDB file                /Fe<file> name executable file
/Fm[file] name map file                 /Fo<file> name object file
/Fp<file> name precompiled header file  /Fr[file] name source browser file
/FR[file] name extended .SBR file       /Fi[file] name preprocessed file
/doc[file] process XML documentation comments and optionally name the .xdc file

                              -PREPROCESSOR-

/AI<dir> add to assembly search path    /FU<file> forced using assembly/module
/C don't strip comments                 /D<name>{=|#}<text> define macro
/E preprocess to stdout                 /EP preprocess to stdout, no #line
/P preprocess to file                   /Fx merge injected code to file
/FI<file> name forced include file      /U<name> remove predefined macro
/u remove all predefined macros         /I<dir> add to include search path
/X ignore "standard places"

                                -LANGUAGE-

/Zi enable debugging information        /Z7 enable old-style debug info
/Zp[n] pack structs on n-byte boundary  /Za disable extensions
/Ze enable extensions (default)         /Zl omit default library name in .OBJ
/Zg generate function prototypes        /Zs syntax check only
/vd{0|1|2} disable/enable vtordisp      /vm<x> type of pointers to members
/Zc:arg1[,arg2] C++ language conformance, where arguments can be:
    forScope[-] - enforce Standard C++ for scoping rules
    wchar_t[-] - wchar_t is the native type, not a typedef
    auto[-] - enforce the new Standard C++ meaning for auto
    trigraphs[-] - enable trigraphs (off by default)
/openmp enable OpenMP 2.0 language extensions

                              -MISCELLANEOUS-

@<file> options response file           /?, /help print this help message
/bigobj generate extended object format /c compile only, no link
/errorReport:option Report internal compiler errors to Microsoft
    none - do not send report
(press <return> to continue)
    prompt - prompt to immediately send report
    queue - at next admin logon, prompt to send report (default)
    send - send report automatically
/FC use full pathnames in diagnostics   /H<num> max external name length
/J default char type is unsigned
/MP[n] use up to 'n' processes for compilation
/nologo suppress copyright message      /showIncludes show include file names
/Tc<source file> compile file as .c     /Tp<source file> compile file as .cpp
/TC compile all files as .c             /TP compile all files as .cpp
/V<string> set version string           /w disable all warnings
/wd<n> disable warning n                /we<n> treat warning n as an error
/wo<n> issue warning n once             /w<l><n> set warning level 1-4 for n
/W<n> set warning level (default n=1)   /Wall enable all warnings
/WL enable one line diagnostics         /WX treat warnings as errors
/Yc[file] create .PCH file              /Yd put debug info in every .OBJ
/Yl[sym] inject .PCH ref for debug lib  /Yu[file] use .PCH file
/Y- disable all PCH options             /Zm<n> max memory alloc (% of default)
/Wp64 enable 64 bit porting warnings

                                -LINKING-

/LD Create .DLL                         /LDd Create .DLL debug library
/LN Create a .netmodule                 /F<num> set stack size
/link [linker options and libraries]    /MD link with MSVCRT.LIB
/MT link with LIBCMT.LIB                /MDd link with MSVCRTD.LIB debug lib
/MTd link with LIBCMTD.LIB debug lib


c:\Users\ukhan\Documents\Auto_Security\Test_Code>
```

Basically I am trying to generate assembly code for MIPS R4000 from Microsoft Visual C++.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you believe this should be possible to begin with?

Comment: Correction - the actual option is /QMmipsX and I did try with /QMmips1 and the option is also invalid.

What makes me think its possible?  Well, that's what the Microsoft documentation says:

Switch  Description  Default status
/QMmips1

Comment: mdsn says that it is only for Visual Studio 2005

Comment: MIPS is not supported on VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a build of the desktop version of Windows that ran on MIPS, it was discontinued in 2000 due to lack of use. Much the same happened to the mobile version, struck by an apple in 2010.  Accordingly, the compiler support was discontinued as well, you need VS2008 or less.

The cross compiler in VS2008 is present in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\bin\x86_mips.  A snip from the options displayed with /?:

```
/QMmips2 MIPS II ISA (default)          /QMmips3 MIPS III ISA
/QMmips4 MIPS IV ISA                    /QMmips5 MIPS V ISA
/QMmips16 MIPS 16 ASE                   /QMmips32 MIPS 32 ISA
/QMmips64 MIPS 64 ISA
/QMn32[-] generate code for MIPS n32 mode
/QMR3900 optimize for r3900             /QMR4100 optimize for r4100
/QMR4200 optimize for r4200             /QMR4300 optimize for r4300
/QMR5400 optimize for r5400             /QMVIPER optimize for Viper
/QMRFWCE generic WinCE -QMFPE- MIPS     /QMRWCE generic WinCE MIPS (Default)
/QMFPE[-] use floating point emulation  /QMase3D use MIPS-3D ASE
```

VS2008 is still available through a reseller like Amazon, is free with an MSDN subscription or can be obtained through an auction site like Ebay.  The Professional edition is required to get mobile support.