# Making a Listing File using /fa in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mips, mars-simulator

Time for my first post! I'm currently working on trying to transpose a C++ code into assembly using the MARS simulator for an assignment, and I was wanting to use the `/fa filename` function that Visual Studio has to create an .asm file to get a bit of a preview of what I need to do (Incredibly new to assembly, professor hasn't been too wonderful at teaching much of anything about it, so I'm having difficulties). My question is, how exactly do I use the `/fa filename` in Visual Studio? The C++ code I'm transposing is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printBar (int n) {
   int k;
   for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
      cout << '*';
   }
   cout << endl;
}

int main () {
   int numPts;
   int value;
   int j;
   cin >> numPts;
   for (j = 1; j <= numPts; j++) {
      cin >> value;
      printBar (value);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I just don't have any experience with using Visual Studio, so I don't quite understand where I'd put the command for the listing file. I've tried using the disassembler during a debugging, but it doesn't resemble anything recognizable. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe that Visual Studio doesn't support compiling to MIPS anymore. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114991/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-compile-for-mips)

Comment: On the Start Menu/Screen, open "Visual Studio Tools" then run the "Developer Command Prompt."  Find your source file.  Run `cl /FA my_source.cpp`.  Note that you're going to get an awful lot of output for a C++ program that uses the C++ Standard Library because so much of the standard library code is in the header.  Use the C Standard Library (`printf` and friends) to simplify the output.  As has been noted by others, Visual C++ does not support targeting MIPS.  The Developer Command Prompt will configure the tools for x86; there are other shortcuts under Visual Studio Tools for other targets.

Comment: Could I possibly use an older version of Visual Studio, or another program totally, to see a possible MIPS output? I've seen it using `gcc` in UNIX, but that doesn't exactly help my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 does not support compiling to MIPS. It compiles to ia32 or maybe x64 if you have a 64 bit system.

Looking at ia32 assembly will absolutely not help you program in MIPS assembly since the two instruction sets are so very different.  Looking at x64 assembly *might* be useful.

I think you set the /FA option in the Project/Build options dialog, but I don't have a copy of VS2013 to confirm this.